# I need the SQL query as per my requirement

Tags: sql

Hi I need the SQL query for the image is attached , In this we have used only one table i.e. assetstatus

current output taken from this query

```
select * from assetstatus WHERE assetnum = 'DY2867'
```

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vwui.png)

And I required this output ( In the condition if isrunning is 0 then the date contains in change date will be considered as Start date and if isrunning is 1 then the date contains in change date will be considered as End  date and the value for downtime will fetch from when isruuning is 1
[Desired output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7i5z.png)

i tried several query but did not worked

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Please post what you have already tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would need more information to answer accurately. The images are inconvenient; it would be better if your code and results (as relevant) were all included in your question as text / code. I would also need a better understanding of your data structure and to know which database platform you are using (Postgres, MySQL, MSSQL etc). Making some assumptions, the below may help:

Firstly, I don't know if what you want can be done with a single (or nested) SQL statement alone. This is because there appears to be an implicit structure in your data which depends on composite and variable values (namely your isrunning and changetime fields). Because the changetime field has variable values (timestamps?), it cannot be used aggregate rows by using, for example, a GROUP BY clause. I might be wrong but here's one way it could be done in any case.

Write a PL function to return the result-set you want as follows.

I have made the assumption that there are only ever two rows for each start / running period. Of these two rows, the isrunning=1 row will always have the higher (most recent) changedate value (to be used as 'End date'. Also, the table is some kind of log so changedate will only ever increase as entries are added. Assuming the aforementioned, the first of each two rows always has isrunning=0 and the second has isrunning=1 and row1.changedate<row2.changedate.  I think it's those pairs of rows you are asking to aggregate into each row of your desired result set.

If this is all correct, I think the PL processing would look like this (in crude pseudocode, I haven't written the actual code because I don't think it will help if my database platform PL language differs from yours):

```
1. Set up a your DB platform's version of an array of records (I'll call it 'my_resultset') where each record holds the fields typed as per the fields you want in each of your result-set fields).

2. LOOP through the query: 
select * from assetstatus where assetnum = 'DY2867' order by changedate asc; 

3. Store the row in a variable we'll call 'current_row' per your database's 
 flavour of PL.

4. IF isrunning = 0 THEN
A. Initialise a new record variable (to store in the array).
B. set your new record variable startdate:=current_row.changedate. 
END IF

IF isrunning = 1 THEN
A. set your new record variable enddate := current_row.changedate
B. set your new record variable downtime := current_row.downtime
C. set all other fields in new record from current_row as appropriate
D. push the record on to my_resultset
END IF

RETURN my_resultset as per your language specific syntax etc.
```